# windows 8.1 upgrade from win 8 fails with error code 0xc1900101-0x20017

Tags: windows, upgrade

I just tried to install windows 8.1 on my laptop, but it fails to install with the message:

Sorry we couldn't complete the update to Windows 8.1.
We restored your previous version of Windows to this PC
0xC1900101 - 0x20017
The update installed just fine on my desktop. The difference between the two machines is that the desktop has media center install, and isn't using TrueCrypt.

On the first reboot for the update, the laptop goes to the PC restore screen. Thus far I have just been selecting "Continue to windows 8."

in other forum suggested me to decrypt hdd before upgrade. but i'm confused how to doing that. anyone can explain to me?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED - I had this same issue issue. I disconnected all unnecessary devices and updated the drivers for my Nvidia graphics card. After this the windows 8.1 update worked without a hitch